# List iterator to add the missing value back to the list

Tags: java, arraylist, listiterator

I am trying to insert integer values into a list.Once the values are inserted, I will be checking whether the current and next values have a difference of 10 between each.If yes, I will be adding 10 to the first value and add it back the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrayList.add(20);
        arrayList.add(40);
        arrayList.add(50);
        arrayList.add(70);
        arrayList.add(90);

        ListIterator<Integer> iterator = arrayList.listIterator();
        int firstVal = 0;
        int secVal = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                firstVal = iterator.previous();
                iterator.next();
            }

            secVal = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("FirstValue " + firstVal);
            System.out.println("secVal " + secVal);
            if (firstVal != 0) {
                if ((secVal - firstVal) > 10) {
                    //iterator.previousIndex();
                    iterator.add(firstVal + 10);
                    firstVal = 0;
                    iterator.next();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("iterator " + iterator.toString());

    }
```

Two things i can't able to make it work correctly.

Firstly when I am trying to add the difference value back to the list, it is not added to the correct index.For example, the First value is 20 and the second value is 40, the new value 30 is added after 40.

Secondly, the missing value between 70 & 90 which is 80 is not created here.

Kindly correct me on the logic which I am missing here.

thanks for your time.

Comment: What are you expecting `previousIndex()` to do? Read the Javadoc for that method and see whether it does what you expect.

Comment: @tgdavies Actually it did nothing for my case and commented it now.Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: You should not comment it out. You need to call `previous()`

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks a lot .you highlighted what the issue was.

Comment: @user7 modified to previous() in my actual code..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc of [`previousIndex()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previousIndex()):

> Returns the index of the element that would be returned by a subsequent call to `previous()`. (Returns -1 if the list iterator is at the beginning of the list.)

It does not, in any way, change the iterator position.

Use [`previous()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()) for that:

> Returns the previous element in the list **and moves the cursor position backwards**. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list backwards, or intermixed with calls to `next()` to go back and forth. (Note that alternating calls to `next` and `previous` will return the same element repeatedly.)

Comment: @ Andreas, Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.It fixed the issue.Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you find that the difference between two elements are more than 10 and when you insert, instead of calling `iterator.previous();` you are calling `iterator.previousIndex();`

Comment: Wow , thank you.It actually fixed both the issues.thanks a ton